Convert animated .blend file to .dea file
I'm trying to convert a .blend file using blender into a .dea file to use in xcode. I first backed action and then clicked on export then Collada. In the settings I enabled "Include Animations" and exported it. Then I opened the exported file using xcode but instead of my 3d model, it's just a blue cube. My object was an animated water.

I also exported it to "Universal Scene Description" including animation. Blender gives me a .usdc file (~5GB) which I can preview by clicking on space bar on my macbook and it shows it correctly with animation and everything. Then I opened it with xcode; xcode doesn't even animate it and there is no button to start the animation. However there is a button ""Export to scenekit" which gives me .scn file (~85MB). The picture below as a refrence.

This file can be used in ARkit but it is still not animated. Also when I open this .scn file in xcode, it shows a play button and when I click on it the water doesn't animate.
Thank you in advance.
